# How to model a simple market equilibrium with linear programming?

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, economics

I want to model the following problem. The problem is well-known in economics. demand-supply curve equilibrium.
Is there any straight forward technique to solve the equilibrium point obtained by an inverse linear function (demand) and a step-wise competitive supply function.
There might be some constraints to solve this?
the following picture shows the problem.

[image: demand-supply equilibrium]